# C помощью Jqury добавить в css: no-repeat;

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Мой код

```
$("#multyArrowsReversUp").css({ "backgroundImage": "no-repeat" });
```

Эта строчка работает

```
`$("#multyArrowsReversUp").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

В таблице стилей я рааботаю с background так. И всё работает.

```
background: url(../../images/CST/Vector-Arrow_ANIM_Blue.gif) center center no-repeat;
```

Comment: Если вы думаете, что хорошо описали проблему - вы заблуждаетесь

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Добавил подробностей

Comment: `.css({ "backgroundRepeat": "no-repeat" });` или `.css({ "background": "url(../../images/CST/Vector-Arrow_ANIM_Blue.gif) center center no-repeat" });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так посмотри, что пишется в [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-image). А потом загляни в [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background):

> Свойство является [сокращением,](/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) которое устанавливает следующие свойства в одном объявлении: [`background-clip`](/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip), [`background-color`](/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-color), [`background-image`](/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-image), [`background-origin`](/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin), [`background-position`](/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-position), [`background-repeat`](/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat), [`background-size`](/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), и [`background-attachment`](/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment).

И выбери правильное имя свойства - [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat).

Comment: Спасибо. Работает как часы.